# What theorem tells us that any local maximum or minimum occurs at a critical point?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is there a formal name to this theorem, if yes/no what is a way to formally state this result? I ask because I am being told to state a theorem about local extrema occurring at critical points but I am unaware of any theorem besides simply stating "Any local max or min is a critical point"

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_(stationary_points)